# npm registry,Is that possible to publish Java or C# libraries in to npm registry

Tags: npm, npm-registry

npm registry,Is that possible to  publish Java or C# libraries in to npm registry.

If so please recommend some articles or details on how to create a private npm registry.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why would you like to use npm, rather than maven (or any other common  jar repository) for java project?

Comment: I am developing cordova plugin, also have to consume those plugins in my Angular Applications as well . and for the other dependencies, am using npm as my registry.So  am wondering whether I can use npm for both. if I could make a private npm registry and host all the dependencies which include my custom cordova plugin .

Comment: i would advise you not to abuse npm registry, but use some other means to store artifacts. did you consider artifactory?